# Code Highlight for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, avr

I have a question and after couple hours searching for the answer I could not find. I am using visual studio to do AVR development. When I use only one file with all my functions and include everything works : Keyword define in my include files like, PINB, or PORTB4 are highlighted in pink, enum in turquoise blue and so long and so forth. But when I write my own .h and .c nothing seems to work properly. In my .h all the colors are correctly displayed, but this file contain hardly any code beside some define and function prototype.

In my .c file that goes along with the .h only words like, int, char, unsigned and long are colored blue like they should. is there a way to get my color highlighted in my library .c file?

Thanks you all
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to add every .c files associated with my .h in the Source Files folder of my project!

Took me some time, but figured it out!